# RequestError: TransportError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'failed to parse')

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Creating an index:

```
def create_index(index_name):
    es=create_elastic_search_object()
    entry_mapping = {
    'entry-type': {
        'properties': {
            'text': {'type': 'string'},
            'coordinates': {'type': 'geo_point'},
            'username':{'type': 'string'} }
            }
            }
    es.indices.create(index_name,body={'mappings':entry_mapping})
```

Inserting into the index

```
coordinates= str(tweet[0][0])+","+str(tweet[0][1])
es.index(index=index_name, doc_type=keyword, id=start_id+ind, body={'text': tweet[1],'coordinates': coordinates,'username': tweet[2]})
```

Error:

```
*** RequestError: TransportError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'failed to parse')
```

Debugging:

```
(Pdb) body={'text': tweet[1],'coordinates': coordinates,'username': tweet[2]} 
(Pdb) print body
{'username': 'csd', 'text': 'RT @funder: Court Doc:Trump evicted a disabled US Veteran because he had a therapy dog\n\n@votevets #trumprussia #resist #theresistance #russ...', 'coordinates': '-117.1304909,32.7211149'}
```

All formats seem correct to me, what am I missing?

Libraries used:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
```

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: i have the same issue, i'm now using ES version 5.1

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I suspect this is happening because I'm sending a non-existing geopoint (wrong latitude or longitude value)

Answer (score 1):

When I had the same problem, in my case, I had NULL value in my dict, so just check your data or try to cast your values to str before reading.